# Does JIRA autocomplete query database every time?

Tags: autocomplete, jira

JIRA's autocomplete is impressive, it can almost auto-complete everything everywhere. I wonder how JIRA implements in efficient way? If every typing needs to query sever side database, it should not be able to response swiftly.

Comment: Why should it not be able to respond swiftly?

Comment: Have a look at the Network monitor in your browser when it autocompletes. It may be using AJAX - that's pretty slow - or maybe Web Sockets or long-polling.

Answer (score 2):

No, JIRA embeds all the data needed for JQL autocomplete into a hidden fieldset in the page you are viewing. You can view it in the page source, as seen in the attached screenshot:

[image: JQL Autocomplete Data]